# CSS, switch left/right to transform/translate for better performance

Tags: css, performance, css-animations, css-transforms

I found this good CSS animation for a progress bar.

But I want to `transform: translate` instead of `left/right`.

How can I switch to `transform` it? I tried but it doesn't work:

https://codepen.io/shalimano/pen/wBmNGJ

```css
body{
  background:#ffffff;
  margin:50px 300px;
}

.slider{
  position:absolute;
  width:1000px;
  height:5px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.line{
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background:#4a8df8;
  width:150%;
  height:5px;
}

.subline{
  position:absolute;
  background:#4a8df8;
  height:5px; 
}
.inc{
animation: increase 2s infinite;
}
.dec{
animation: decrease 2s 0.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes increase {
 from { left: -5%; width: 5%; }
 to { left: 130%; width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes decrease {
 from { left: -80%; width: 80%; }
 to { left: 110%; width: 10%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
   <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="subline inc"></div>
  <div class="subline dec"></div>
</div>
```

**First attempt**:

```
@keyframes increase {
 from { transform: translateX(-5%); width: 5%; }
 to { transform: translateX(130%); width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes decrease {
 from { transform: translateX(-100%); width: 80%; }
 to { transform: translateX(1100%); width: 10%;}
}
```

But it's not the same.

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks. Updated.

Comment: percentage of left/top are relative to parent size and percentage of translate are relative to child size : so it's a matter of calculation

Comment: @TemaniAfif ohh! I still don't know how to do... :(

Comment: by the way, you will not win a lot in perf because you are also animating width so you should probably change width by scale in order to have a good perf

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh wow! Can you write an example? Is it simple?

Comment: Post your HTML as well, and use the Stack Snippet button when editing your post. That way, we can actually execute your code.

Comment: @BramVanroy I posted codepen: https://codepen.io/shalimano/pen/wBmNGJ

I don't know how to use StackOverflow snippet button.

Comment: @BramVanroy one moment.

Comment: @BramVanroy DONE! Snippet here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the fact that percentage value with `translate` are related to **the element size** and not **parent size** like `top`/`left` and in order to have good performance you need to also replace the `width` by `scale` so that you only use transform and you will not [trigger layout changes](https://csstriggers.com/width).

Here is an approximation of your code using only transform:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 5px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: rgba(74, 141, 248, 0.4);
}

.slider:before,
.slider:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #4a8df8;
  height: 5px;
  width:100%;
  transform:scaleX(0);
  animation: increase 2s infinite linear;
}

.slider:after {
  animation-delay:1s;
}

@keyframes increase {
  from {
    transform:translateX(0%) scaleX(0);
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  60% {
    transform:translateX(0%) scaleX(0.5);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
  80% {
    transform:translateX(20%) scaleX(0.3);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(0%) scaleX(0);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: Why `transform:scaleX(0);` on `.slider:before,.slider:after {`?

Comment: @FredHors it's the same as the initial state of the animation .. the after element is having a delay so the animation will start only after 1s and before this the element is full width so we add scaleX(0) to keep invisible until the animation starts. Remove it and you will see the effect

Comment: thanks a lot. One last question: I knew there is a special css property that say the browser this element or the elements in it are animations at human eye, do you remember? Can this help performance?

Answer (score -1):

One of the main differences between the two methods (`transform: translate` and `left` ) of positioning elements is how they react to percentages. You can use `px`.